# Wordpress dashboard blank screen

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, dashboard

I'm a newbie to Wordpress. I'm using Ubuntu. Just now I've installed Wordpress on my machine. When I click on the links in dashboard, it doesn't show any elements. I saw my database `wordpress` which contains some tables by default. My screen looks like below.

[image: Blank Wordpress Admin Dashboard]

When I click on any of the links in the left sidebar, I can't see any content in the main page.

But I'm able to see my site in `http://localhost/wordpress/`. I can't see contents in dashboard. Am I missing anything??? Someone help me please.

Comment: Could this be caused by the `.htaccess` rewrite rules not working because WordPress is in a sub directory?

Comment: @Malachi yes, in sub directory called wordpress

Comment: @Malachi folder structure is `/var/www/wordpress` where `/var/www` is my root

Comment: Please check the page source and see if there's any Fatal error message

Comment: @DanielPatilea No errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this one helps:

1. Open file blog/wp-admin/includes/screen.php in your favorite text
   editor.
2. On line 706 find the following PHP statement: `<?php echo self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
3. Replace it with the statement: `<?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
4. Save your changes.

Comment: yes, something there with `_help_sidebar;`. I found `<?php echo self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>`. replace with what?

Comment: replace with this: <?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>

Comment: Can you explain please

Comment: There is a bug in your WordPress version causing the issue.

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: Are you using the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be caused by a plugin. Try to rename the `/plugins` folder on your site; this will disable all of your plugins and you can find out if this is the problem.

Comment: If you renamed your folder, check your dashboard and see if it works

Comment: go to /var/www/wordpress/wp-content and you'll find the /plugins folder

Comment: `/plugins` folder exists. How to rename it? I mean by what?

Comment: folder_old or any other name